# "Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member."..Error happening when trying to give value to an object in an Array in Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, parsing, iteration

First I created a custom class:

```
  class TVInfo {
  var cast : [String]
  var name : String
  var charecterName : String

init (cast: [String], name: String, charecterName: String){

    self.cast = cast
    self.name = name
    self.charecterName = charecterName
 }
}
```

Then I try and parse the JSON data

```
 let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as!
      NSDictionary

 let cast = jsonResult.objectForKey("cast") as! NSArray
          for item in cast
          {
          let name = item["name"] as! String
          let charecterName = item["character_name"] as! String

          }
let TV = TVInfo(cast: cast as! [String], name: cast[0].name, charecterName: cast[0].charecterName)
```

but I keep getting the error "Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member 'charecterName'". It's strange because the first constant- "name" appears to have value but it's in the same array as "characterName". How can I properly give value to the characterName constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are extracting `name` from `item` and `character_name` from `jsonResult` but you're ignoring the results by trying to access the properties by dot notation which fails.

I guess you want to achieve something like this

```
let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as!
  NSDictionary

var infoArray = [TVInfo]()
let cast = jsonResult.objectForKey("cast") as! [[String:String]]
for item in cast {
  let name = item["name"]!
  let charecterName = item["character_name"]!
  let TV = TVInfo(cast: cast, name: name, charecterName: charecterName)
  infoArray.append(TV)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but there are more constants than the ones I posted that's why I had "cast" setup as an array. Example:                        
          let network = jsonResult["network"] as! String
          let cast = jsonResult.objectForKey("cast") as! NSArray
          for item in cast
          {
          let name = item["name"] as! String
          let charecterName = jsonResult["character_name"] as! String

          }
          let overview = jsonResult["overview"] as! String                                      So I'm not sure if the method you are proposing with work.

Comment: Your repeat loop is useless because the scope of `name` and `charecterName` is restricted to within the curly braces. the variables are not accessible outside the loop. And the compiler doesn't know of what type `cast[0]` is

Comment: I meant it to say item["character_name"] as! String.  Why is it I can extract the data for name but not for characterName?

Comment: You can, but you have to declare the variables in a broader context. Again, with your code you can't use the variables outside the repeat loop

Comment: How about something like this:                                                                                        let cast = jsonResult.objectForKey("cast") as! NSArray
          let item = cast[0] as! [String:String]
          let name = item["name"]!
          let charecterName = item["character_name"]!

Comment: That seems to be logical.

Comment: I just tried that code, It ran but then this error came up: thread 1 exc_bad_access (code=exc_i386_gpflt)

Comment: It crashes because `cast` is not `[String]`, it might be `[[String:AnyObject]]` or even `[[String:String]]`, an array of `String:AnyObject` or `String:String` dictionaries.

Comment: The [[String:AnyObject]] worked! But it's only giving me the first name while there are multiple names.  I was trying to iterate over the array earlier but it wasn't working properly. Any idea on how to get all the names out?

Comment: I have no idea about the JSON structure but I updated the answer with a suggestion to create an array of `TVInfo` to get all items out of `cast`.